# How to get my output looking below?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am developing a android application in that I have a page called invitation that is looking like below, in that image John and Danny is my `textview` output.

If I tap any of the text view I need to show my current `textview` name with three buttons immediate below panel, not as popup as show in below diagram

```
______________________________________
|                                    |
| John Bday                          |
|____________________________________|
|                                    |
| Dany Bday  (on tap)                |
|____________________________________|
|                                    |
|  Dany Bday                         |
|   _       _        _               |
|  |_|YES  |_|No    |_| May Be       |
|____________________________________|
```

i have textview code here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

can anyone help me.Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnclickListener()` method on the `TextView`.
In the `onClick()` method, make the changes you require.

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView setTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setTV); 



//use the id of the TextView where you want to set the name to instead of setTV

name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        void onClick(View view) {
             String name = name.getText().toString();
             setTV.setText(name);
        }

});
```

Keep this `TextView setTV` in the `xml` file too. just do not set any text to it. So, nothing will be shown. And only when the `name` `TextView` is clicked, this text will be set to the `setTV` and will be visible.

This could also be done dynamically. For that you can check other resources on how to add `TextView` dynamically.

For the `CheckBox` and `Button`, this approach of statical initialization can be taken where initially they are set as invisible by setting the value of `android:visibility="gone"`.

And dynamically setting them back to be visible in the `onClick()` method.
by calling the `setVisiblity(View.Visible);` method on the `Button` or `CheckBox`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the xml Layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
 android:showDividers="middle"
 android:dividerPadding="5dp"
 android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<--the layout for showing the pop up kinda thing with visibility flase 
with id="hidden"-->
</LinearLayout>
```

and programatically you need the set the visibility to true, based on onTouchListener.

Like this:

```
View.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.findElementById("hidden");
            v.setVisibility(true);
        }
 }
```

adding multiple values can be done using the use of custom adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: when run my code it give "missing return statement" error

Comment: Where did you exactly get that error? @Selva Simon p

Comment: that error occur after complete setVisibility(true); now it is solved i am added "return true;" statement there then it is solved.

Comment: i am added layout (id:hidden) as u mentioned above but when run time the hidden layout is not visible.

Comment: i am added hidden layout as you mentioned above but when i am click the hidden layout is not show in my app.

Comment: Without complete code predicting things is not easy can you edit your question accordingly?